# How To Dynamically Access Specific Attribute In A List of Data Frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, attributes

I have a data which is a list of data frames. I am trying to access a specific attribute inside each of the data frames in the list. It's possible to extract the specific attribute `DP.UniqueId` using below code.

```
> attr(new_data$A$AA, "SpotfireColumnMetaData")$DP.UniqueId
[1] "A-024"
```

Problem with this approach is that it's not dynamic. Also, the big data I have has thousands of data frames in the list and for each of the data frames I want to extract this specific `DP.UniqueId` attribute.

If I have to apply `lapply()` or `for loop()` to get this attribute dynamically, then I will have to reference it as:

```
> attr(new_data[1][1], "SpotfireColumnMetaData")$DP.UniqueId
NULL
```

But it looks like in `R`, `attr()` can't be referenced like above code does. Is there a way to extract specific attributes dynamically and store it in a data frame?

**Data**

```
new_data <- list(A = structure(list(AA = structure(5.49485, SpotfireColumnMetaData = list(
  DP.TestNumber = "111", DP.Type = "", DP.TestName = "ABC", 
  DP.Info = "PTR", DP.TestUnit = "Mohm", DP.Statistic = "raw", 
  DP.Program = "", DP.ScaleFactor = 0L, DP.FilteredOutCells = 0L, 
  Limits.Prod.Lower = 2, Limits.Prod.Target = NaN, Limits.Prod.Upper = 7, 
  Limits.Spec.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Spec.Target = NaN, Limits.Spec.Upper = Inf, 
  Limits.Outlier.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Outlier.Target = NaN, 
  Limits.Outlier.Upper = Inf, Limits.Whatif.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Whatif.Target = NaN, 
  Limits.Whatif.Upper = Inf, DP.ParamType = "PARAMETRIC", DP.BlockId = "", 
  DP.Scratch = "", DP.ColumnId = "", Dp.BaseName = "", DP.FTR.testtxt = "", 
  DP.PTR.testtxt = "A  -1 <> B", DP.DTR.textdat = "", 
  DP.MPR.pinnum = "0", DP.UniqueId = "A-024"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L)),
  B = structure(list(BB = structure(0.08707662, SpotfireColumnMetaData = list(
  DP.TestNumber = "112", DP.Type = "", DP.TestName = "ABC", 
DP.Info = "PTR", DP.TestUnit = "Mohm", DP.Statistic = "raw", 
DP.Program = "", DP.ScaleFactor = 0L, DP.FilteredOutCells = 0L, 
Limits.Prod.Lower = 2, Limits.Prod.Target = NaN, Limits.Prod.Upper = 7, 
Limits.Spec.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Spec.Target = NaN, Limits.Spec.Upper = Inf, 
Limits.Outlier.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Outlier.Target = NaN, 
Limits.Outlier.Upper = Inf, Limits.Whatif.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Whatif.Target = NaN, 
Limits.Whatif.Upper = Inf, DP.ParamType = "PARAMETRIC", DP.BlockId = "", 
DP.Scratch = "", DP.ColumnId = "", Dp.BaseName = "", DP.FTR.testtxt = "", 
DP.PTR.testtxt = "A  -1 <> B", DP.DTR.textdat = "", 
DP.MPR.pinnum = "0", DP.UniqueId = "B-025"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can accomplish this easily with the `purrr` package. For example

```
library(purrr)
new_data %>% map(pluck, 1, attr_getter("SpotfireColumnMetaData"), "DP.UniqueId")
# $A
# [1] "A-024"
# $B
# [1] "B-025"
```

The `map()` will iterate over the initial list, and then `pluck()` can take care of the deep extraction.

Comment: .@MrFlick - Thanks. Is it possible to assign these IDs as the first row of respective data frame in the list?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Is that a different question?

Comment: .@MrFlick - Yes. I forgot to write it in the question. Please check the update. Your answer is correct with respect to what I asked first time.

Comment: You really shouldn't change questions after they have been answered. You should ask a new question instead. Basically you are asking something different: basically how does one add a new row to each data.frame in a list.

Comment: .@MrFlick - I agree. Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624083/how-to-add-specific-attribute-as-a-new-row-to-respective-data-frame-in-a-list). I am avoiding new questions to ensure I don't get restricted by StackOverflow in terms of when I can ask my next questions. Even after giving good reproducible examples, I don't get up votes (even if question has been answered) and that triggers StackOverflow's algorithm.