# How To Add Specific Attribute As A New Row To Respective Data Frame In A List

Tags: r, list, dataframe, attributes

I have a list of data frames in which I want to read a specific attribute and then append it as the first row the respective data frame to which that attribute belongs.

In below data, I want to read `DP.UniqueId` dynamically which can be done as follows, but not sure how to append it as first row of the data frame that `DP.UniqueId` belongs to so that I get output as shown in sample output.

```
library(purrr)
new_data %>% map(pluck, 1, attr_getter("SpotfireColumnMetaData"), "DP.UniqueId")
# $A
# [1] "A-024"
# $B
# [1] "B-025"
```

Above code credit [@MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623575/how-to-dynamically-access-specific-attribute-in-a-list-of-data-frames).

This I want to do dynamically as the big data I have has thousands of data frames in the list.

**Data**

```
new_data <- list(A = structure(list(AA = structure(5.49485, SpotfireColumnMetaData = list(
  DP.TestNumber = "111", DP.Type = "", DP.TestName = "ABC", 
  DP.Info = "PTR", DP.TestUnit = "Mohm", DP.Statistic = "raw", 
  DP.Program = "", DP.ScaleFactor = 0L, DP.FilteredOutCells = 0L, 
  Limits.Prod.Lower = 2, Limits.Prod.Target = NaN, Limits.Prod.Upper = 7, 
  Limits.Spec.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Spec.Target = NaN, Limits.Spec.Upper = Inf, 
  Limits.Outlier.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Outlier.Target = NaN, 
  Limits.Outlier.Upper = Inf, Limits.Whatif.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Whatif.Target = NaN, 
  Limits.Whatif.Upper = Inf, DP.ParamType = "PARAMETRIC", DP.BlockId = "", 
  DP.Scratch = "", DP.ColumnId = "", Dp.BaseName = "", DP.FTR.testtxt = "", 
  DP.PTR.testtxt = "A  -1 <> B", DP.DTR.textdat = "", 
  DP.MPR.pinnum = "0", DP.UniqueId = "A-024"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L)),
  B = structure(list(BB = structure(0.08707662, SpotfireColumnMetaData = list(
  DP.TestNumber = "112", DP.Type = "", DP.TestName = "ABC", 
DP.Info = "PTR", DP.TestUnit = "Mohm", DP.Statistic = "raw", 
DP.Program = "", DP.ScaleFactor = 0L, DP.FilteredOutCells = 0L, 
Limits.Prod.Lower = 2, Limits.Prod.Target = NaN, Limits.Prod.Upper = 7, 
Limits.Spec.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Spec.Target = NaN, Limits.Spec.Upper = Inf, 
Limits.Outlier.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Outlier.Target = NaN, 
Limits.Outlier.Upper = Inf, Limits.Whatif.Lower = -Inf, Limits.Whatif.Target = NaN, 
Limits.Whatif.Upper = Inf, DP.ParamType = "PARAMETRIC", DP.BlockId = "", 
DP.Scratch = "", DP.ColumnId = "", Dp.BaseName = "", DP.FTR.testtxt = "", 
DP.PTR.testtxt = "A  -1 <> B", DP.DTR.textdat = "", 
DP.MPR.pinnum = "0", DP.UniqueId = "B-025"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L)))
```

**Sample Output**

```
$A
       AA
1 A-024
2 5.49485

$B
          BB
1 B-025
2 0.08707662
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R we can do

```
lapply(new_data, function(x) rbind(attr(x[[1]],"SpotfireColumnMetaData")$DP.UniqueId,x))

$A
       AA
1   A-024
2 5.49485

$B 
         BB
1      B-025
2 0.08707662
```